# Mongo DB increment if statement (Meteor App)

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, handlebars.js

I cannot seem to get around this seemingly simple issue.

The code below allows me to add or subtract the number of likes by 1 on my post objects.

I would like to be able to do the following:

**If postLikes = 0 then stop allowing me to reduce the number of likes.**

I don't want to be able to reduce number of likes past 0.

Here is my code:

```
Template.post.events({
  "click .likeButton": function() {
    // Set the checked property to the opposite of its current value
    Posts.update(this._id, {
      $inc: {
        postLikes: 1
      }
    });
  },
  "click .dislikeButton": function() {

    // Set the checked property to the opposite of its current value

    Posts.update(this._id, {
      $inc: {
        postLikes: -1
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, what about having a condition before your update?

Update - Never mind. Better way to accomplish this is via the query!

```
"click .dislikeButton": function() {
    Posts.update({_id : this._id, postLikes : {$gt : 0}}, {
      $inc: {
        postLikes: -1
      }
    });
}
```

Comment: Worked an absolute charm. Thanks!

Comment: This is a silly way to accomplish this.  The first argument to `update` is a selector where you can specify criteria to restrict the update.  It accepts `{_id:this._id, postLikes:{$gt: 0}}` and will not update the doc if the condition is not meant.

Answer (score 0):

Your modifier will only be applied *if* a document matches the criteria in the first argument of  `update', the selector.  I see the accepted answer but really just use one db call and let the db check object criteria where possible.  Like this:

```
"click .dislikeButton": function() {
  Posts.update({ _id: this._id, postLikes:{ $gt: 0 }}, { $inc: { postLikes: -1 }});
}
```

See [documentation on Mongo update](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/) and [Meteor's update](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/update).